# This is a question when using openweather API with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, openweathermap

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Todays Reports</h1>
    <img :src="icon" alt="" />
    <h2> <span>{{ city }}</span> 's weather <br />
      <b> {{ dsc }}</b>
    </h2>
    <p>temp: {{ temp }}<span>&#176;</span></p>
    <form>
      <h3>
        <span> 도시</span>를 입력하세요
      </h3>
      <input type="text" v-model="city" />
      <!-- <button @click="weatherData">확인</button> -->
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  import background from "@/assets/background";
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        bg: background,
        icon: "",
        dsc: "",
        temp: "",
        city: "seoul",
        mainDsc: ''
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.weatherData();
    },
    updated() {
      this.weatherData();
    },
    methods: {
      weatherData() {
        axios
          .get(
            " https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + this.city + "&appid=209427778b168dd3cfb8c77b931a8344&units=metric"
          )
          .then((response) => {
            let data = response.data;

            console.log(this.city)
            this.dsc = data.weather[0].main;
            // main 설명글
            this.mainDsc = data.weather[0].main
            this.temp = data.main.temp;

            this.icon = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + data.weather[0].icon + "@2x.png";

            const container = document.querySelector('#container')
            for (let i = 0; i < this.bg.length; i++) {
              if (this.mainDsc == this.bg[i].main) {
                container.style.background = this.bg[i].background
              }
            }

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

It has been implemented to some extent, but it is not different, and when the weatherData keyup.enter event is performed on the input, it is set to the default setting, seoul. It contains the input entered by the user as v-model, but I don't know why!

If I call the function with updated, it runs, but if I press enter, it changes back to Seoul..!

Advice from experts please

Answer (score 1):

Every time you hit enter, it submits the form. The default behavior for form submission reloads the component, which then by default returns 'seoul' for city.

Try binding an event listener to the form's submission, and comment out the method call on update(). This will prevent excessive API calls.

```
<form @submit.prevent="weatherData">
      <h3><span> 도시</span>를 입력하세요</h3>
      <input type="text" v-model="city" />
      <button>확인</button>
    </form>
```

Conversely, if you want the method to fire on input event, you should validate the input value before sending the API call, as some of the shorter entries throw a 404.

Comment: much better answer, i'm removing my answer :)